# Changing the language through "/i18n/setlang/" ajax POST is not doing anything on Firefox

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, internationalization

My backend uses Django and my front end is done with ReactJS.

When users change their profile's language, I perform a POST ajax call to `/i18n/setlang/` with the data object `{language: [language_code]}` and refresh the page.

I simply have this ajax call to change the language, a bunch of .po/.mo files with the translations and I am using gettext() to translate the lines in JS.

This works perfectly on Chrome but is completely ignored on Firefox and no translation is done. Any idea why?

My middleware contains the `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware` and my LOCALE_PATH is set as such:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

LOCALE_PATHS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale')
]
```

---

### UPDATE

On chrome the value `request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']` is

`fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,pl;q=0.6`

(all the languages that I support)
whereas on Firefox, it returns :

`en,en-US;q=0.5`

Still not sure why...

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1375471) regarding this issue

Comment: So there is no way to translate your website on Firefox?

Comment: I would try re-installing/upgrading your version of Firefox

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by saving the user preferences in the database when doing the AJAX call, and then updating the `session[translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY]` value when the user gets the main page view.

```
from django.utils import translation

class MainPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return super(MainPageView, self).get(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

    profile = request.user.profile

    if profile.preferred_language is None or profile.preferred_language == "":
        profile.preferred_language = request.LANGUAGE_CODE
        profile.save()
    else:
        request.session[translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = profile.preferred_language

    return super(MainPageView, self).get(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
```